# Can't put "/var/lib/dpkg/info" on a new partition with the debian installer

Tags: linux, debian, partition, debian-installer

I put `/var/lib/dpkg/info` on a new partition and put everything else in "/var" on another partition (suggestion 2 in [#21941](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=21941.)). Every partition was mounted with the defaults flag and nothing else (no noexec etc) during the installation.

Somehow, the installer for Debian buster failed to install new packages to the hard drive.

If I don't make a new partition for `/var/lib/dpkg/info`, the installer works fine.

What went wrong?

Comment: For now, I ask the debian installer to leave a partition unmounted. After installation, I mount that partition as /var/lib/dpkg/info2, move everything in /var/lib/dpkg/info, and mount the partition as /var/lib/dpkg/info.

Comment: If I make a new partition for "/var/lib/dpkg" instead of "/var/lib/dpkg/info", the installer works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's difficult to say what went wrong in this particular case without suitable logs or debug output, in general, most programs don't gracefully handle arbitrary directories being mountpoints.

There are various top-level directories (e.g., `/usr`, `/var`, `/home`) that can successfully be mountpoints, and there are other directories maintained by one particular program that can often be mountpoints (e.g., `/var/lib/mysql`), but most programs don't test for arbitrary directories they use becoming mountpoints, so you'll often find that this results in breakage.  If you very much want this to work, you can ask the dpkg maintainers to fix it, and it may be fixed in the release after bullseye (since bullseye is mostly frozen now).  But otherwise, the general recommendation is to avoid doing this and live with the fact that `/var` is not mounted `noexec`.

Comment: When i try to apt-get install ufw, dpkg creates a temporary /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci folder to hold the decompressed .deb file. https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2001/04/msg01074.html Running the scripts within the tmp.ci folder requires exec.

Comment: Yes, I appreciate that; I read the bug report.  What I'm saying is that this isn't supported on Debian and generally isn't in most cases for most programs on most Unix systems, so you just need to gracefully deal with the fact that `/var` has to be exec in Debian.